# In ASP.NET Core MVC, how to show the post creator's username in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to make a forum web app using ASP.NET Core MVC and Identity. My `ForumPost` model looks like this:

```cs
public class ForumPost
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string PostName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PostBody { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
}
```

I'm storing the `IdentityUser` here so in the Posts table, it is replaced by a foreign key to the user `Id` in the Users table, as explained [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship).
The `Create` method in my controller looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("PostId,PostName,PostBody")] ForumPost forumPost)
{
    ModelState.Clear();

    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    forumPost.User = user;

    if (TryValidateModel(forumPost))
    {
        _context.Add(forumPost);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(forumPost);
}
```

But when I try to show the creator's `Username` in the `Index.cshtml`, it comes up blank. This is the shortened `.cshtml`:

```cs
@model IEnumerable<ForumPost>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.UserName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure there is enough information to determine this, but from what I can see I think you need to send a model to your `Index` action you are calling in your `Create` action. You would need this: `return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), forumPost)`

Comment: I am not sure this would work for you or not without seeing the `Index` action declaration code. If your Index action takes in a PostId, then you would need to send `forumPost.PostId` as your RedirectToAction route param.

Comment: You would not want to use IdentityUser as the type that is exposing your stored post object to the client.  Instead, you should think about pulling the data from the database via a separate object since IdentityUser will most likely be tied to the current user's session, not the user who made the post.

Comment: @JustSomeDude Oh right, I can just make a separate Post view model that shows only the Post Name and the creator Username and use that with my Index action.

Comment: @DavidL Ahh. Yeah, it probably won't be best to get the entire IdentityUser either, since the Post only really needs the user Id  and username.

Comment: As a security measure, be careful to not expose UserId to the client as rendered html.  That is probably not something you typically want to expose.

Comment: @DavidL Thank you for the advice! In my case, the user Id is a generated string guid. I'm currently using the Scaffold Identity for now, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), since I'm still learning about .NET Core. But yeah, it's probably best to query using the username to get to the user's public profile.

Answer (score 0):

In the original post, I assumed (and assumed wrong) that the `User` field in the `ForumPost` is filled in by **automatically** grabbing the `IdentityUser` from the Users table using the foreign key assigned to the `ForumPost`. It ended up not being the case, and I really don't need the entire user details, just the username.

Therefore, I've changed my `ForumPost` code to this:

```
public class ForumPost
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string PostName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PostBody { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
}
```

I've added the `UserId` there so that the following `Index` action can have access to it. Doing this won't change the database, since the database already has a User Id foreign key pointing to the Users table. Here is the new `Index` action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var posts = await _context.Posts.ToListAsync();
    var postList = new List<PostIndexModel>();
    foreach (var p in  posts)
    {
        var userName = (from u in _context.Users
                    where u.Id.Equals(p.UserId)
                    select u.UserName).SingleOrDefault();
        var post = new PostIndexModel()
        {
            PostId = p.PostId,
            PostName = p.PostName,
            UserName = userName
        };

        postList.Add(post);
    }

    return View(postList);
}
```

I've also created a new `PostIndexModel` view model that only shows a few things:

```
public class PostIndexModel
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Post Name")]
    public string PostName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Post Creator")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```